# What is wrong with my Binary Search algorithm implementation?

Tags: java

I apologize for asking such a simple question. But I'm stumped. I think I've implemented the solution using the correct algorithm but for some reason I'm getting a stackoverlow error when I run this. Any help?

```
public class BinarySearch {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] a = new int[]{1,3,5,9,10,100,210,423,500};
    System.out.println(binarySearch(a,5,0,a.length-1));
}
static int binarySearch(int a[], int x, int left, int right){
    if(left>right)
        return -1;
    int mid = left+right/2;

    if(a[mid] < x){
        return binarySearch(a,x,mid+1,right);
    }
    else if (a[mid] > x){
        return binarySearch(a,x,left,mid-1);
    }
    return mid;
}
```

Comment: What exact error are you getting? Can you post your console output?

Comment: You are missing parentheses around `int mid = left+right/2;`. Should be `int mid = (left+right)/2;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're calculating the value for `mid`, your scope is not proper.

`int mid = left+right/2`

vs

`int mid = (left+right)/2`

While this is a simple solution to your problem, you should also checkout Peter's and Laune's suggestions. They both handle integer overflows.

If the length of the array is equal to or close to the max value of the int datatype in Java, you might run into some issues.

Comment: ideally `int mid = (left + right) >>> 1` to avoid overflows ;) +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey I prefer `mid = left + (right-left)/2` but this is a matter of taste (for me: as it avoids the language specific operator)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Can you ever have an array where left+right overflows? Got a program to prove it?

Comment: Use int mid= (left + right)/2 that will give correct algorithm

Comment: @laune Here you go: [example](http://ideone.com/cKAiru). `(left + right) / 2` calculates `(left + right)`, assigns the value to `int`, then divides by two. So if `(left + right)` doesn't fit in 32 bits, you'll get overflow before dividing by `2`, ending up with the wrong result. With bitwise operations (>>>1), the shift will be performed before the "conversion" to a 32 bit integer, so you'll not have overflow.

Comment: @PeterLawrey overflows? what overflows would integer division cause? you're dividing by 2 here, not by -1!

Comment: @Mishax see my previous comment. It's the sum that overflows, not the division.

Comment: @BackSlash I don't believe you, I believe the result of addition of two 32 bit ints is always a 32 bit int. Is what you describe in the JLS?

Comment: @Mishax Can you please sum up `1111` and `1111` and prove me that the result will fit in 4 bits and there is no overflow? I don't know if there is a JLS, what I can tell you is that JLS is not necessary. It's simply how binary math works.

Comment: @BackSlash Don't underrate me. I'm perfectly aware of the result of doubling Integer.MAX_VALUE. Re-read my comment.

Comment: @BackSlash JLS is the Java Language Specification. And I know what overflow is and how it occurs. But I'm looking to see how the spec on binary numeric promotion is explaining this. Specifically 15.18.2 says "The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the promoted type of its operands." For two ints, that's int. I don't see how what comes after that comes into play.

Comment: @Mishax For two ints, that's int, sure. But what will happen if you sum up two `int`s which sum overflows the integer's max value? It will overflow, and the result will be "adjusted" to stay in 32 bits and be representable with `int`. i.e. if you sum up `2147483647` and `5`, the result should be `2147483652`, but `2147483652` exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so it overflows (doesn't fit in 32 bits) and ends up being represented as the [32-bits integer `-2147483644`](http://ideone.com/cmWkWm), which as you can see is not the desired result.

Comment: @BackSlash ok but then you can't say "with bitwise operations the shift will be performed before the 'conversion' to a 32 bit integer".. If I evaluate (-294967296 >>> 1) it will give me 2000000000, not -147483648 regardless if I arrived at -294967296 by evaluating 2 * 2000000000 and overflowing, or through some other non-overflowing expression.

Comment: Mixing arithmetic and bitwise operators will get your CERT revoked: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM01-J.+Do+not+perform+bitwise+and+arithmetic+operations+on+the+same+data

Comment: @Mishax It seems I'm not that able to explain myself. Please read [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search), especially the "Extra credit" section, it will resolve all your doubts.

Comment: @Mishax `Integer.MAX_VALUE + Integer.MAX_VALUE = -2`. `-2 / 2 = -1`. `-2 >>> 1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @PeterLawrey ok I see what you're saying - this works because the values left and right there will never be negative in Java, and because Java doesn't have an unsigned int there's no other more elegant way of doing that. But what is the case we're talking about here, arrays with 1 billion elements or more? That's huge!